# moz box orient not working though webkit box orient is

Tags: html, css

HTML Code:

```
<div id="nav">
    <div id="home_menu">
        <a href="home.php">Home</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="feed.php">Feed</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="">Notifications</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <a href="profile.php">Profile</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="">Settings</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Styling:

```
#nav {
    float:right;
    margin-top: 12px;
    width: 200px;
    display:box;
    display:-webkit-box;
    display:-moz-box;
    display:-ms-flexbox;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

The code works perfectly on chrome but the orient is vertical and not horizontal on mozilla. Please help!

Comment: Which version of firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to your class

(display:-moz-box; is old syntax)

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NhSPq/1/)**

A good place to start when trying to get the syntax right for all browsers is http://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/ [although some properties which they generate for you are not necessary and can be removed]

Answer (score 2):

@Anubhav Awasthy Just Put /* autoprefixer: off */ above the line of code which are disappearing it will ignore by build.

eg.
  /* autoprefixer: off */
  `-webkit-box-orient: vertical;`